# How to run WebSocket and HTTP Server on the same port using ReactPHP and Ratchet?

Tags: php, http, websocket, ratchet, reactphp

I've the following code:

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$socketServer = new \React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8080', $loop);

$httpServer = new \React\Http\Server(function(\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) {
  return new \React\Http\Response(200, [
      'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
    ],
    'Hello, World'
  );
});

$httpServer->listen($socketServer);

$rrServer = new RRServer(); // Implements MessageComponentInterface

$webSocketServer = new IoServer(
  new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
      $rrServer
    )
  ),
  $socketServer,
  $loop
);

$webSocketServer->run();
```

The code works, but I'm only able to access it using http://localhost:8080, and when I try to connect using WebSocket, the connection is opened, and then it immediately closes. Also, When I create a new socket with different port then I'm able to access both using http:// and ws://

What's wrong with my code?
How can I run WebSocket and HTTP Server on the same port?

Answer (score 4):

Hey ReactPHP core team member here. In short you can listen with two servers on one port using `so_reuseport` on the socket server but that only sort of round robins connections to either of them. What you can do is try the suggestions cboden and I did here and lets us know if you had any issues with those: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/771#issuecomment-569439423

Which are namely:

- Your code is trying to attach two SocketServer's to the same port. You need to attach a single SocketServer to one port, then re-route traffic based on a condition of your choosing (HTTP header, endpoint, or sub-domain for example). See https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/blob/master/src/Ratchet/App.php class or some of https://github.com/reactphp/http/blob/master/examples/82-server-upgrade-chat.php for some inspiration.
- Take a look at: https://github.com/voryx/WebSocketMiddleware

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

For now, I've created two sockets one for handling WebSocket and another for handling HTTP Requests.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not run multi websocket in same port. but you can join all websockets in one. and separate them with url query like this.

- http://localhost:8080?source=socket_1
- http://localhost:8080?source=socket_2

and in your code can get source of request by :

```
function onOpen( ConnectionInterface $conn ) {
    $querystring = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery()->toArray();
    if($querystring['source'] == 'socket_1'){
        // run socket 1 jobs
    else{
        // do socket 2
    }
    // and change
}
```

I didnt do it and i didnt test it. so ... :)

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is to run the WebSocket and the HTTP Server on one Socket but it's not working.